# Solr 2 nodes setup not working with zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solr9

I have a 2 solr node setup with 3 zookeeper nodes.I was running with 8.11 version and it was working all fine. Now, I have upgraded solr nodes to 9.12 and when I start solr service on both of them, it starts on 1 node but never start on the other one. The configurations are correct as I have started the solr service on each and it works with one node but never works with two nodes.

doing sudo service solr status, gives me

```
ERROR: Failed to get system information from http://localhost:8983/solr due to: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Parse error : <p>
  Searching for Solr?<br/>
  You must type the correct path.<br/>
  Solr will respond.
</p>
```

Looking into solr logs it says
`2023-05-25 19:00:32.043 WARN  (qtp1978504976-24) [   ] o.e.j.s.HttpChannel /solr/admin/info/system => javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down. at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:157) javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down. at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:157) ~[jetty-server-10.0.13.jar:10.0.13] at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.13.jar:10.0.13] at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301) ~[jetty-rewrite-10.0.13.jar:10.0.13]`

nb I am running the same configurations as I were in solr 8,

Can someone help me here

I have tried changing chroot path, but in that case I always get livenodes as 1. my solr.in.sh file on both solr nodes include
ZK_HOST="{zookeeper1IP},{zookeeper2IP},{zookeeper3IP}:2181"

Comment: Look at the startup log - the entry you've included is just the symptom - i.e. that the corecontainer didn't start as it should. Could be a permission issue after upgrading?

Comment: I have checked and changed permissions of installation dir, home, data dir, env file to solr user. I have already one node which is running and my suspision is that it adds the other nodes as same names localhost:8983_solr. I changed the solr context property in solrconfig.xml and it worked with livenodes as 2. but in that case I am not able to access the web console

Comment: Hurray! after long days, sleepless nights and frustrated mornings, I was able to resolve the issue. It was config issue. What I did

changed jetty url from localhost to 0.0.0.0 which was not opening solr UI to the world. 

I had two java versions and it was not getting one out of it, though I changed the version with alternatives but it didn't helped. I added Java home property to solr.in.sh file

I kept everything else the same way it was and now I can run those 2 solr nodes with 3 zookeepers and can access the web console as well